# Using tax_query in get_terms

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

i want to query my custom taxonomy which has a another custom taxonomy

```
 $tag_id=1;
$txy="channels";
    $args = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'series',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => $txy,
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $tag_id
         )
      )
    );

    $series =get_terms( $args );
```

but it seem to query everything

Comment: `tax_query` is not valid for get_terms https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

Comment: i see. what's a better way to query such taxonomy to achieve what i want to do?

Comment: Your question is still unclear as to what you are trying to do and what the days structure is.